# "One from England" VS "One of chemistry."

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

> - Jack met the student from England and I met the ***one*** from France.
> - Jack met the student of physics and I met the ***one*** of chemistry.
>
> Note: examples are from Geoffrey Poole's Syntactic Theory.

Why ***one*** can be substituted for student in the first sentence , while in the second sentence can't be?

Comment: Does *Syntactic Theory* not explain it, or do you not have access to the explanation for some reason?

Comment: It doesn't explain them. @sumelic

Comment: This was asked at ELL and deemed (by me, at least) beyond our remit there. Poole is at pains to say that he _can't_ explain it from a syntactic perspective (I think, although I don't pretend to any but a bystander's knowledge of such things). Chomsky is summoned, universal grammer is mooted, and we are off to the races. See **[this.](https://books.google.com/books?id=qakcBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA12)**

Comment: Do you have a reference that says it can't, as opposed to possibly sounding a little off (only) in this particular sentence?

Comment: Compare: *he'd like a picture of cows and one of sheep*.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a syntactician, but I hypothesise...

The phrase "student of X" is a syntactic unit and cannot have any of its parts substituted. Thus the *student of physics* cannot become *one of chemistry* or *student of it.* *Student of X* must remain complete (of course, a different subject can be named, but neither *student* nor the subject can be substituted by a pronoun of some sort).

> Jack met the student of physics and I met the student of chemistry.
>   *Jack met the student of physics and I met the one of chemistry.
>   *Jack met one student of physics and I met the other student of it.

However, using *from* means that "student from England" contains three units and each of the principal terms **can** be substituted.

> Jack met the student from England and I met the one from France.
>   Jack met the student from England and I met the tutor from there.
>   Jack met a student from England and I met another from France.
>   etc.

Comment: _"I ate the salad of endives and she ate the one of kale"_ seems much less egregious that the example. Is it only _student of_ for which this is true? (I  now see Poole's question: how is it that, without analysis, English speakers "just know" that the example with Jack is wrong, without in most cases being able to explain what is wrong with it, and why.)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a problem that vexes even the most serious linguists, I have only a suggestion to propose: that "one" in this construction can be a placeholder for something that functions as a definitive, single-option identifier within a category.  In other words, it works for words where one modifier ***rules out some other modifiers***.

*If you're tall, you can't be short.  If you're right, you can't be wrong.  If something is smooth, it can't be rough.*

Someone can be both a student of physics and of chemistry, without any confusion.  But to say someone is *from France* and *from England* is ambiguous and somewhat off-putting.  It makes it unclear where the person is originally from, or when they were "from" each place.  In that sense, being *from* somewhere is a **definitive trait**.

On the other hand, being a *student of chemistry* is not definitive.  One could be a student of chemistry, physics, and art history.

In this sense, it seems to me to be less a question of *syntax* than of *semantics*.  Consider that the second sentence could be rewritten with the objects of the prepositional phrases used as adjectives modifying the student.

> Jack met the **physics student** and I met the **chemistry student**.

It would still sound unnatural to write:

> Jack met the **physics student** and I met the **chemistry one**.

But why?  It isn't a problem with other phrases of identical construction.

> Sally ate the **red popsicle** and I ate the **blue one**.
>
> Jim was the **right man**, and Tom was the **wrong one**.

Being red or blue are likewise *definitive, single-option traits*.  They describe the object in a way that clearly divides the two options into discrete possibilities.  Because the options are clearly distinct, replacement with a pronoun is more natural.